# CHMOD and how the permissions thing works?

Tags: permissions, users, chmod, read-only, restricted-access

So I got few questions about CHMOD and permissions in general.

I know there are 3 groups:

- user(the creator of the file, the admin user (?) )
- groups
- others

My questions are:

- Can I create more than 1 group and assign different permissions to
  each one of them, or does it include every group that I'll create in
  the big group of "groups" which got permissions for itself and for
  the "groups" inside of it?
- How can I create a directory and make permissions so only the creator (user) will be able to modify it but the rest will be able to browse but not modify it.
  I'v tried to set

> ```
> CHMOD u+wrx ~/random
> CHMOD go+r ~/random
> ls -l
> drwxr--r-- 2 john john 4096 Feb 10 03:33 random
> ```

I have created before that a group called `friends` and a user called `friend` and assigned him to this group.
So I tried to login to friend and write `cd ~/random` and I got a message of "access denied" although I added a read permission to "group".

- What does execute permission on a directory signify?

What do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I create more than 1 group and assign different permissions to
> each one of them?

Yes, you can. But you'll have to use [ACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) instead of the basic permission scheme. This way, you can assign different types of permissions to multiple users and groups.

> How can I create a directory and make permissions so only the creator (user) will be able to modify it but the rest will be able to browse but not modify it?

By executing `chmod 0755 folder`. Note that users can still modify files if they have the permission on a per-file basis (rename and deletion of files is not possible though).

> What does execute permission on a directory signify?

The execute bit applied to a directory allows you to *enter* the given directory. You will also need the read bit to list the content of the directory.